# comparing ndarray with values in 1D array to get a mask

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy array, 2D and 1D respectively.
I want to obtain a 2D binary mask where each element of the mask is true if it matches any of the element of 1D array.

Example

```
 2D array 
 -----------
 1 2 3 
 4 9 6
 7 2 3


 1D array 
 -----------
 1,9,3

 Expected output
 ---------------
 True   False  True
 False  True   False
 False  False  True
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `np.in1d`. Although `np.in1d` returns a 1D array, you could simply reshape the result afterwards:

```
In [174]: arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,9,6],[7,2,3]])

In [175]: bag = [1,9,3]

In [177]: np.in1d(arr, bag).reshape(arr.shape)
Out[177]: 
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Note that `in1d` is checking of the elements in `arr` match *any* of the elements in `bag`. In contrast, `arr == bag` tests if the elements of `arr` equal the broadcasted elements of `bag` *element-wise*. You can see the difference by permuting `bag`:

```
In [179]: arr == np.array([1,3,9])
Out[179]: 
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

In [180]: np.in1d(arr, [1,3,9]).reshape(arr.shape)
Out[180]: 
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

---

When you compare two arrays of unequal shape, NumPy tries to [broadcast](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) the two arrays to a single compatible shape before testing for equality. In this case, `[1, 3, 9]` gets broadcasted to

```
array([[1, 3, 9],
       [1, 3, 9],
       [1, 3, 9]])
```

since new axes are added on the left. You can check the effect of broadcasting this way:

```
In [181]: np.broadcast_arrays(arr, [1,3,9])
Out[185]: 
[array([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 9, 6],
        [7, 2, 3]]), 
 array([[1, 3, 9],
        [1, 3, 9],
        [1, 3, 9]])]
```

Once the two arrays are broadcasted up to a common shape, equality is tested
*element-wise*, which means the values in corresponding locations are tested for
equality. In the top row, for example, the equality tests are `1 == 1`, `2 == 3`, `3 == 9`. Hence,

```
In [179]: arr == np.array([1,3,9])
Out[179]: 
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: cool, I tried a==b before posting the question but didnt work, if you could please elborate more on your explanation, what exactly you mean by "tests if the elements of arr equal the broadcasted elements of bag element-wise"

Answer (score 1):

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,9,6],[7,2,3]])
b = np.array([1,9,3])
```

Have you tried this:

```
print a == b
## array([[ True, False,  True],
##        [False,  True, False],
##        [False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Look up broadcasting (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to see why this works.

Comment: It seems the order of elements in `b` shouldn't matter, so such a direct comparison won't work. If you must use `broadcasting`, you could do : `(a[...,None] == b).any(-1)`. Of course, the preferred method for memory efficiency purposes would be with `np.in1d` as stated in [`@unutbu's answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35564191/3293881).